# Index was outside the bounds of the array. at OracleInternal.I18N.UTF16ConvUtility.GetRemainingBytes

Tags: c#, entity-framework, oracle11g, oracle-manageddataaccess

Index was outside the bounds of the array. at OracleInternal.I18N.UTF16ConvUtility.GetRemainingBytes

Unexplainable error is happening every time and nothing online about it

```
 var job = db.Jobs.FirstOrDefault(x => !x.IsDone);
```

causes

`` System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array. at OracleInternal.I18N.UTF16ConvUtility.GetRemainingBytes(Int32 numBytesToRead, Byte[] buffer1, Int32 offset1, Int32 buffer1Bytes, IList`1 bytes, Int32& currSegIndex, Int32& continuationOffset, Byte[] dstBuffer) at OracleInternal.I18N.UTF16ConvAL16UTF16.ConvertBytesToChars(IList`1 bytes, Int32 bytesOffset, Int32 bytesCount, Char[] chars, Int32 charOffset, Int32& charCount, Boolean bUseReplacementChar) at OracleInternal.I18N.Conv.ConvertBytesToString(IList`1 bytes, Int32 bytesOffset, Int32 bytesCount, Char[] chars, Boolean bUseReplacementChar) at OracleInternal.I18N.Conv.ConvertBytesToString(IList`1 bytes, Char[] chars, Boolean bUseReplacementChar) at OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.OracleClobImpl.GetCompleteClobData(Int32 currentRow, Int32 columnIndex, OracleConnectionImpl connImpl, Byte[] lobLocator, DataUnmarshaller dataUnmarshaller, TTCLobAccessor lobAccessor, OracleClobImpl& oraClobImpl) at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleDataReader.GetValue(Int32 i) at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper.ErrorHandlingValueReader`1.GetUntypedValueDefault(DbDataReader reader, Int32 ordinal) at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper.ErrorHandlingValueReader`1.GetValue(DbDataReader reader, Int32 ordinal) at lambda_method(Closure , Shaper ) at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper.HandleEntityAppendOnly[TEntity](Func`2 constructEntityDelegate, EntityKey entityKey, EntitySet entitySet) at lambda_method(Closure , Shaper ) at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Coordinator`1.ReadNextElement(Shaper shaper) at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper`1.SimpleEnumerator.MoveNext() at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext() at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source) at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.<GetElementFunction>b__1[TResult](IEnumerable`1 sequence) at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.ExecuteSingle[TResult](IEnumerable`1 query, Expression queryRoot) at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression) at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.DbQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression) at System.Linq.Queryable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate) at XX.XX.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\XXX\Program.cs:line xx ``

Job class

```
  public class Job
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string SomeClob { get; set; }

        [Index]
        public bool IsDone { get; set; }


    }
```

Comment: Please format the stack trace more readably, with one line per stack frame, just as you'd normally see it.

Comment: Also, you've tagged this linq-to-sql, but isn't `System.Data.Entity` for Entity Framework, not LINQ to SQL?

Comment: i think it is still LINQ to SQL

Comment: @Toolkit Read `System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization`, that's exactly EF, not LINQ to SQL

Comment: ok, I replaced with EF

Answer (score 0):

You should post this on the ODP.NET Oracle forum, along with a simple repro.  It looks like a provider bug.

https://community.oracle.com/community/database/developer-tools/windows_and_.net/odp.net

Comment: seems like string can't be longer than 68339 chars. Any ideas?